# Combining Same Oracle SQL Scripts in One?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, bi-publisher, oracle-bi

I have four identical scripts that only have one value that varies between them that I would like to combine into one script with four multiple outputs.  The reason for this is BI Publisher will not render multiple x-axis dates between multiple scripts, so I trying to make it so it renders as one script.  The following is the same script for all four:

```
select to_char("DATA_POINT_DAILY_AVG"."DATE_OF_AVG", 'DD-MON-YY') as "DATE_OF_AVG",
        "DATA_POINT_DAILY_AVG"."VALUE" as "DAILY_AVG_VALUE"
 from   "TEST"."COMPONENT" "COMPONENT",
        "TEST"."COMPONENT_DATA_POINT" "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT",
        "TEST"."DATA_POINT_DAILY_AVG" "DATA_POINT_DAILY_AVG" 
 where  "COMPONENT"."SITE_ID" = ('123abc')
  and   "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."COMPONENT_ID"="COMPONENT"."ID"
  and "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."NAME"='TEST_1'
  and "DATA_POINT_DAILY_AVG"."COMPONENT_DATA_POINT_ID" = "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."ID"
  and "DATA_POINT_DAILY_AVG"."SITE_ID" = "COMPONENT"."SITE_ID"
  and  "DATA_POINT_DAILY_AVG"."DATE_OF_AVG" between ('01-FEB-17') and ('28-FEB-17') 
 order by "DATA_POINT_DAILY_AVG"."DATE_OF_AVG" desc;
```

the only line that varies between the four scripts is:

```
  and "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."NAME"='TEST_1'
```

which would be as follows for all four (i.e.,):

```
  and "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."NAME"='TEST_1'
  and "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."NAME"='TEST_2'
  and "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."NAME"='TEST_3'
  and "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."NAME"='TEST_4'
```

Everything else is identical...expected output would be:

```
DATE_OF_AVG           DAILY_AVG_VALUE_1         DAILY_AVG_VALUE_2           DAILY_AVG_VALUE_3           DAILY_AVG_VALUE_4
-----------           -----------------         -----------------           -----------------           -----------------
06-FEB-17                           0                           0                           0                           0
05-FEB-17                           0                           0                           0                           0
04-FEB-17                           0                           0                           0                           0
03-FEB-17                           0                           0                           0                           0
02-FEB-17                           0                           0                           0                           0
01-FEB-17                           0                           0                           0                           0
```

One date column, with four different values based on the various "TEST_x" values.

I hope this makes sense, and any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."NAME", 
        to_char("DATA_POINT_DAILY_AVG"."DATE_OF_AVG", 'DD-MON-YY') as "DATE_OF_AVG",
        "DATA_POINT_DAILY_AVG"."VALUE" as "DAILY_AVG_VALUE"
 from   "TEST"."COMPONENT" "COMPONENT",
        "TEST"."COMPONENT_DATA_POINT" "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT",
        "TEST"."DATA_POINT_DAILY_AVG" "DATA_POINT_DAILY_AVG" 
 where  "COMPONENT"."SITE_ID" = ('123abc')
  and   "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."COMPONENT_ID"="COMPONENT"."ID"

  and "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."NAME" IN ('TEST_1','TEST_2','TEST_3','TEST_4')

  and "DATA_POINT_DAILY_AVG"."COMPONENT_DATA_POINT_ID" = "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."ID"
  and "DATA_POINT_DAILY_AVG"."SITE_ID" = "COMPONENT"."SITE_ID"
  and  "DATA_POINT_DAILY_AVG"."DATE_OF_AVG" between ('01-FEB-17') and ('28-FEB-17') 
 order by  "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."NAME", 
           "DATA_POINT_DAILY_AVG"."DATE_OF_AVG" desc;
```

it will produce a result like this:

```
NAME    DATE_OF_AVG           DAILY_AVG_VALUE_1         DAILY_AVG_VALUE_2           DAILY_AVG_VALUE_3           DAILY_AVG_VALUE_4
----    -----------           -----------------         -----------------           -----------------           -----------------
TEST1     06-FEB-17                           0                           0                           0                           0
TEST1     05-FEB-17                           0                           0                           0                           0
....
....

TEST2     06-FEB-17                           0                           0                           0                           0
TEST2     05-FEB-17                           0                           0                           0                           0
....
....
TEST3     06-FEB-17                           0                           0                           0                           0
TEST3     05-FEB-17                           0                           0                           0                           0
....
....
```

Comment: Is this pivoting the data? I don't get how it does it, could you give some explanaition of the query?